# Proguard in Android Studio: Running proguardRelease complains of unresolved references

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use Proguard for my release in Android Studio.

I have the classic problem that everyone has which is the "Unresolved references to classes or interfaces".

Like I read everywhere, I tried to add `-dontwarn` command to the proguard-project.txt file but it doesn't change anything.

Maybe my setup just ignore the proguard-project.txt file? Everything seems ok but I'm new to Android Studio, gradle and proguard so maybe I'm missing something! Any help is appreciated.

Here are my files:

proguard-project.txt

```
-dontwarn org.apache.**
```

project.properties

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-15
android.library=false
```

Current warning I receive

```
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.Coders$1: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.X86Options
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.Coders$1: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.PowerPCOptions
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.Coders$1: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.IA64Options
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.Coders$1: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.ARMOptions
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.Coders$1: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.ARMThumbOptions
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.Coders$1: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.SPARCOptions
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.Coders$BCJDecoder: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.FilterOptions
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.Coders$BCJDecoder: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.FinishableWrapperOutputStream
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.Coders$BCJDecoder: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.FilterOptions
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.Coders$BCJDecoder: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.FinishableOutputStream
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.Coders$LZMADecoder: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.LZMAInputStream
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.DeltaDecoder: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.DeltaOptions
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.DeltaDecoder: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.FinishableWrapperOutputStream
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.DeltaDecoder: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.DeltaOptions
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.DeltaDecoder: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.UnsupportedOptionsException
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.LZMA2Decoder: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.LZMA2Options
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.LZMA2Decoder: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.LZMA2InputStream
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.LZMA2Decoder: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.FinishableWrapperOutputStream
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.LZMA2Decoder: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.LZMA2Options
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.LZMA2Decoder: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.FinishableOutputStream
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.LZMA2Decoder: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.LZMA2Options
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.lzma.LZMACompressorInputStream: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.LZMAInputStream
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.xz.XZCompressorInputStream: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.XZ
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.xz.XZCompressorInputStream: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.XZInputStream
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.xz.XZCompressorInputStream: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.SingleXZInputStream
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.xz.XZCompressorInputStream: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.XZ
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.xz.XZCompressorOutputStream: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.XZOutputStream
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.xz.XZCompressorOutputStream: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.LZMA2Options
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.xz.XZCompressorOutputStream: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.XZOutputStream
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.xz.XZCompressorOutputStream: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.LZMA2Options
Warning:org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.xz.XZCompressorOutputStream: can't find referenced class org.tukaani.xz.XZOutputStream
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning:org.joda.time.DateMidnight: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.DateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.DateTimeZone: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.DateTimeZone: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Days: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Days: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Duration: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Hours: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Hours: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Instant: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDate: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDate: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Minutes: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Minutes: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.MonthDay: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.MonthDay: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Months: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Months: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.MutableDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.MutableDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.MutablePeriod: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Period: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Seconds: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Seconds: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Weeks: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Weeks: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.YearMonth: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.YearMonth: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Years: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Years: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractDuration: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractInstant: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractPeriod: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.URIException
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.ByteArrayRequestEntity
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.URIException
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.URIException
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.RequestEntity
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnectionManager
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionManagerParams
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.DeleteMethod
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.HeadMethod
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.OptionsMethod
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PutMethod
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.TraceMethod
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnectionManager
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionManagerParams
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnectionManager
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.Header
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.Header
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.Header
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod
Warning:org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.httpclient.Header
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.WireFeedInput
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.WireFeed
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.WireFeedOutput
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.WireFeed
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.WireFeedInput
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.WireFeed
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.WireFeedOutput
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.WireFeed
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.WireFeedInput
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.WireFeed
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.WireFeed
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.WireFeedOutput
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AbstractWireFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.WireFeed
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.atom.Feed
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.RssChannelHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.rss.Channel
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedInput
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedOutput
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedInput
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedOutput
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedInput
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedOutput
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.feed.SyndFeedHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.simpleframework.xml.Root
Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer
Warning:there were 276 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experience here is coming from Eclipse and not Android Studio.  I will typically have my proguard.cfg file in a location at the root level with the project.  And the line inside my project.properties referencing the file would look something like this:

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

while you have this:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Do you also have a file names proguard-android.txt?  I am unfamiliar with the style convention there in your command line.  Perhaps it is a matter of not finding the right file?

Comment: You were VERY close, I just found the problem. In my gradle file, I need to use this to use the "project" configuration too. proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'